# DTS Discontinuity Error while Playing Media File with RTSP Url

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp

I am playing the media file on RTSP by fetching the streams directly from some server. I am getting DTS discontinuity in stream error. I have tried with both FFMPEG and FFPLAY.

**FFMPEG**

I am using the following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://media:123456@10.10.167.20/41415308b3839f2 -f wav test.wav
```

As an output of this command, I am getting the following error:

[image]

**FFPLAY**

I am using the following ffplay command:

```
ffplay rtsp://media:123456@10.10.167.20/41415308b3839f2
```

As an output of this command, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me that when this error usually occurs? Is there any reason behind this and any workaround for this?

Comment: You should have simply copied and pasted the text instead of making an image of text.

Answer (score 3):

From the `libavformat/utils.c`, `avformat_find_stream_info` function:

```
/* Check for a discontinuity in dts. If the difference in dts
 * is more than 1000 times the average packet duration in the
 * sequence, we treat it as a discontinuity. */
```

Also note, that *RTP* does not define any mechanisms for recovering for packet loss.

So, if you lose packets in such manner that the *dts* difference between two read packets is more than 1000 times the average packets duration you get foregoing warning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to ask the reason behind this difference between two read packets. What I need to verify? Because few days ago I was getting streams normally, then why I started getting this packet loss now.

Comment: @BilalAhmedYaseen I read your second question too but it's difficult for me to say what is the reason in this case. Maybe you have some problems with your network. Also you can try to reduce stream bitrate and check results.

Comment: Exactly, it feels me too that there may be some issue with the network. But I want to ask that generally in which circumstances this issue occurs? A how can I verify that this is due to network?

Comment: @BilalAhmedYaseen, I hope this one may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723671/how-to-debug-packet-loss to answer the above questions.